# Peristence using Open JPA ;Setting composite primary key to Id Attribute of Main entity

Tags: jpa, websphere, persistence, ejb-3.0, openjpa

Server - IBM WAS 8.5
Open JPA 2.2.3

I am  trying to perform a container managed persistence using entity manager.

I have the following three entities defined

- Entity **MainEntity** 
  Has an id of the type MainEntityPK
- **MainEntityPK** - has the SubEntity1Code from SubEntity1 table and SubEntity2Code from SubEntity2 Table.
- Entity **SubEntity1** - SubEntity1Code - primary Key
- Entity **SubEntity2** - SubEntity2Code - primary Key

I try to create an entity of MainEntity which has an existing SubEntity1 and SubEntity2 entries

I first find the entities of SubEntity1 and Seg using

```
SubEntity1 SubEntity1 = 
Entitymanager.find(SubEntity1.class,SubEntity1Code)

SubEntity2 subEntity2 = 
Entitymanager.find(SubEntity2.class,SubEntity2Code)
```

The fetch are successful and I have both the instances of subEntity1 and subEntity2

Now I try to set the Primary Key MainEntityPK as follows

```
MainEntityPK MainEntityPK = new 
MainEntityPK(SubEntity1Code,SubEntity2Code);

MainEntity MainEntity = new MainEntity();
MainEntity.setId(MainEntityPK);
```

I am getting following error :

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1802534 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException
: Field: “model.MainEntity.id” of “model.MainEntity@e8df5623” can not be set to “model.MainEntityPK@1768a2” value.
```

I tried removing the setId call and was getting error as follows:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1802534 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException
: Field: “model.MainEntity.id” od “model.MainEntity@e8df5623” can not be set to null value.
```

Can some one help me in identifying what is wrong in setting the instance of MainEntityPK to id attribute of MainEntity

Comment: when i made a sub entity which uses the id of parent entity i use the `@MapsId` annotation.  e.g. `@Id private Long id; @OneToOne @MapsId private Parent parent;`

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provide your actual Entity classes instead of describing them in words.

Comment: The entities have many attributes and will be difficult to comprehend when posted. For the sake of brewity i have just posted the section of interest. Additionally all the entities are serializable and override the equals and hashcode method. If there is any additional information you would require to know i would share them towards getting a better clarity on this issue.

Comment: Update - one entity attribute was getting set null as default value where as the column length was limitied to less than 3 char. Switching to Hibernate highlighted this error and was able to get it resolved.